# Check that the class implements the interface. Kotlin

Tags: reflection, kotlin

I want check that the child class of `SignalPayload`  implements the interface `IConvertible`. How can I do that?

```
sealed class SignalPayload {
    companion object {
        fun trueTypeInstance(type: KClass<SignalPayload>) : SignalPayload? {
          //  if (*** __ KClass<SignalPayload> implemented IConvertible ___  **) 
                ......

        }
    }
}
object Empty : SignalPayload()
data class BadData(val message: String = "BAD") : SignalPayload() {
    override fun toString(): String {
        return message
    }
}
data class payloadString(private var payload: String = "") : SignalPayload(), IConvertible
data class payloadInt(private var payload: Int = 0) : SignalPayload(), IConvertible
data class payloadFloat(private var payload: Float = 0F) : SignalPayload(), IConvertible
data class payloadBool(private var payload: Boolean = false) : SignalPayload(), IConvertible 

interface IConvertible {
    val asBool: Boolean
    val asInt: Int
    val asFloat: Float
    val asString: String
    fun setFromPayload(data: IConvertible)
}
```

How can I do that?

**UPD**
That I had think use it.
Class `SignalChannel` know what field `mPayload` needed (through property `val type: ???`). At first `mPayload` equal Empty

```
interface IArriving {
    fun onNewPayload(data: SignalPayload, sender: IArriving?)
}
interface IConvertible {
    val asBool: Boolean
    val asInt: Int
    val asFloat: Float
    val asString: String
    fun setFromPayload(data: IConvertible)
}

class SignalChannel(val idx: Int, val type: ???, val name: String = "") : IArriving {
var mPayload: SignalPayload = Empty

// when new data arriving - need converting for `type` and refresh field mPayload 
override fun onNewPayload(data: SignalPayload, sender: IArriving?) {
       if ( mPayload is Empty ) { 
           mPayload = SignalPayload.trueTypeInstance(type) // that's my problem
       }
       mPayload.setFromPayload(data)

    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried `is`? From the documentation: `if (yourObj is SignalPayload {
    print(yourObj.length)
}` (https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/typecasts.html)

Comment: "is" from instance of class? yes?

Comment: I need put in "fun trueTypeInstance " name of class. And this function must returned instance of needed class

Comment: What is your use case?

Comment: fun trueTypeInstance(payloadInt::class) --> returned payloadInt()

Comment: fun trueTypeInstance(payloadFloat::class) --> returned payloadFloat(). **But fun trueTypeInstance(BadData::class) -->returned null, because BadData not implemented   IConvertible**

Answer (score 1):

You could make use of proper generics in order to confine the method to types that are both `SignalPayload` **and** `IConverible`:

```
fun <T> trueTypeInstance(): SignalPayload? 
   where T : IConvertible, T : SignalPayload {
     TODO()
}
```

Called like this:

```
SignalPayload.trueTypeInstance<payloadString>() //OK
SignalPayload.trueTypeInstance<Empty>() //Fails
SignalPayload.trueTypeInstance<String>() //Fails
```

Not sure about your use case though...